# Is Repository the only way to save entity data on DB?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm studying Spring boot, and i have create several entity, my problem now is to retrieve the data from controller to save it on db.

Surfing on the web I have learned that i have to use `JPARepositery` or `CrudRepositery` in this way:

An example with User entity

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

and to save

```
User user = new User();
userRepository.save(user);
```

But if I have many entities, Do I need to create a repository for each entity?

I have read about Session, FactorySession and Transaction they are compatible with Spring boot? How it works? and `@Transactional` tag how it works?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One could inject @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager and do data access trough it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually you need to create one `Repository` per `Entity`. This is also a good practice because you are placing operations and queries related to the same `Entity` in the same `Repository`.

Yes, you can obtain a `Session` and a `FactorySession` object (Hibernate), but I would advice you against using Hibernate directy. Instead, it is better to use Spring Data or JPA mechanisms to access your database (just as you do using a `Repository`). The reason is because Hibernate is an implementation of the JPA standard and today we use JPA to access databases (because it masks the exact implementation of the ORM). This way you can later (potentially) replace Hibernate with another JPA implementation (such as EclipseLink) without the need to change your code (in theory). In most projects you will find Hibernate being used, however.

Yes, `Transaction` is a Spring annotation and an important database transaction mechanism in Spring Boot, too.